# Are file deletions in Linux's implementation of NFSv3 synchronous by default?

Tags: linux-kernel, nfs

I see that the NFS client can be instructed to make file *writes* synchronous via the `sync` `mount` option or the `O_SYNC` `open` flag (as they are asynchronous by default), but I don't see any indication of whether file *deletions* are synchronous. [RFC 1813](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#section-3.3.12) doesn't seem to specify client behavior in this case.

From `man 5 nfs`:

> The sync mount option
>
> The NFS client treats the sync mount option differently than some
> other file systems (refer to mount(8) for a description of the generic
> sync and async mount options). If neither sync nor async is specified
> (or if the async option is specified), the NFS client delays sending
> application writes to the server until any of these events occur:
> Memory pressure forces reclamation of system memory resources. An
> application flushes file data explicitly with sync(2), msync(2), or
> fsync(3).
>
> An application closes a file with close(2).
>
> The file is locked/unlocked via fcntl(2).
>
> In other words, under normal circumstances, data written by an
> application may not immediately appear on the server that hosts the
> file. If the sync option is specified on a mount point, any system
> call that writes data to files on that mount point causes that data to
> be flushed to the server before the system call returns control to
> user space. This provides greater data cache coherence among clients,
> but at a significant performance cost.
>
> Applications can use the O_SYNC open flag to force application writes
> to individual files to go to the server immediately without the use of
> the sync mount option.

I would think that deleting/unlinking a file would also `close` it (which *is* specified as being synchronous by default), but I'm not sure of that.

I'm aware that the file may not actually be deleted on the NFS server if there are still hard links pointing to it, but I'm considering that outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Isn't a delete a write on the parent directory?

Comment: @muru I know deleting file requires write permissions on its parent directory, but I'm not familiar with how it's implemented internally. Do you know if that's how NFS treats it?